# How can I generalise this de-serialise method?

Tags: c#

How can I generalize the following de-serialize method?

```
public static bool DeSerializeAnyObject(ref Object MyObj, string fileName)
{

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName)) { return false; }

    FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    try
    {
        MyObj = (MyObj.GetType()) formatter.Deserialize(fs);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Can't De-Serialise" + ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        fs.Close();
    }

   return true; 
}
```

I'm trying to, but can't make a cast by doing this.

```
(MyObj.GetType())
```

How can I make a dynamic cast? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your method never does anything useful - it only assigns a parameter that is not returned. Furthermore it always returns true.

Comment: Since i am on my linux machine i can't give you an example of my stuff but i would do it with generic methods : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/twcad0zb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Since i am on my linux machine i can't give you an example of my stuff but i would do it with generic methods : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/twcad0zb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: @Bas MyObj is changed by reference, that is the intent. I see that I'm a bit mixed up, this behaviour seemed default; Ill add a ref to make it clear.

Comment: @Kickaha The behavior is not default! Normally, a **copy of the reference** is sent to the parameter, the method body then updates the value of the reference to point to your newly deserialized object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite an interesting choice, but for the dynamic casting, you can do `Convert.ChangeType()` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx), but your deserialized object must implement the `IConvertible` interface too.

Something like this:

```
public static bool DeSerializeAnyObject(out Object MyObj, Type MyType, string fileName)
{

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName)) { MyObj = null; return false; }

    FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    try
    {
        MyObj = Convert.ChangeType(MyTypeformatter.Deserialize(fs), MyType);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Can't De-Serialise or Convert: " + ex.ToString());
        MyObj = null;
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        fs.Close();
    }

   return true; 
}
```

Edit: After the further details, you might want to create an additional method to what I proposed to ease the current usage:

```
if (DeSerializeAnyObject(out obj, obj.GetType(), fileName)) {...}
```

and the wrapper method that matches your signature:

```
public static bool DeSerializeAnyObject(ref Object MyObj, string fileName) {
    return DeSerializeAnyObject(out MyObj, MyObj.getType(), fileName);
}
```

Comment: In the end I discovered that passing back an Object allowed me to cast to the desired type in the calling class. I did not need to dynamically determine and cast to the specific object as I knew it in the calling class. You answer most helped me get there, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do a dynamic cast in C#.

However, since you are just assigning to an object, you don't need to cast at all! Just write:

```
MyObj = formatter.Deserialize(fs);
```

Note that because `MyObj` was not passed by reference, this assignment wont *actually* do anything useful for the caller. This is also a very weird thing to do if you ask me.

At least return `MyObj` instead of returning a useless always true `bool`.

You could also do this as a generic:

```
public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string fileName)
{
    T retValue = default(T);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName)) 
        return retValue;

    FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    try
    {
        retValue = (T)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Can't De-Serialise" + ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        fs.Close();
    }

    return retValue;
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you. My issue stemmed from not knowing what type a serialised object was, so that I could reconstruct it correctly from a number of options. The generic does this. Thanks for helping.